# How to use different method to compute Laplace inverse

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform, differential

I was trying to find the inverse of the Laplace transform, which is $L^{-1}(\frac{3s+5}{s^2(s^2+4)})$.
I used Partial Fractions to compute and I got $\frac{3}{4}+\frac{5}{4}t-\frac{3}{4}\cos(2t)-\frac{5}{8}\sin(2t)$.
I wonder if there are other methods that can solve it. I tried to use convolution but couldn't get the same result. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I wonder if there are other methods that can solve it. I tried to use convolution but couldn't get the same result. => what do you mean by tried to use convolution? can you be more precise?

Comment: Yes, I tried to set F(s) = 1/s^2, and G(s) = (3s+5)/s^2+4. And then I try to use the integral of convolution to solve, but the result is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$
\frac{3s+5}{s^2(s^2+4)} = \frac 12\left(\frac{2}{s^2+4}\right)\left(\frac 3s+\frac {5}{s^2}\right)
$$

then

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{3s+5}{s^2(s^2+4)}\right]=\frac 12\int_0^t\sin(2\tau)\left(3+5(t-\tau)\right)d\tau = \frac{3}{4}+\frac{5 t}{4}-\frac{5}{8} \sin (2 t)-\frac{3}{4} \cos (2 t)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, I wonder where this 1/2 comes from?

Comment: To transform $\frac{1}{s^2+4}$ into $\frac 12\frac{2}{s^2+4}$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!